# Will cn1 ever allow native push?

Tags: codenameone

Cn1 offers a push seamless integration using its own servers that takes care of forwarding to fcm/apple servers for you. This works great, but requires a PRO subscription ($79/month)

I love cn1 and want to support the project as much as I can. I want to include push in my app dev, don't mind going through the extra pain of going native and don't find that adding push in my app dev is worth $79/month

I know that part of that cost surely must go towards maintaining the push servers,  so I won't ask for something like bringing cn1 push to basic subscriptions which would be unfair

My point is, can native push be done in cn1. Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it's an opinion-based business question, not a computer programming question. You should probably reach out to CN1 directly: https://www.codenameone.com/contact-us.html

Comment: There are plenty of related questions on stackoverflow and this question could be rephrased "how can native push be implemented in cn1". I just don't get why some people try to limit the scope of a public forum. What is the benefit? Maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't actively blocked it's just unsupported due to the complexity in unifying the vastly different behaviors between iOS and Android. E.g. the parse cn1lib supports its own push which isn't based on our implementation.

I can't tell you how well that works.

It's not something we officially support but it's not something we prohibit.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Reading other stackoverflow posts I got the impression that it wasn't possible but I will look into the parse cn1lib and see if I can replicate it. An answer worth the downvotes!